# Is there any way to exec a stored procedure for all selected data rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm setting up a storekeeping program in which I have 2 tables, one for products and another for `materials`.

In the `products` table, each product has several `materials`. Is there any way to select these rows and decrement `materials` availability?

I tried to use a foreach loop but I couldn't implement it and store each rows data

```
CREATE TABLE materials 
(
    materialID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    materialName NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
    materialAmount INT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE productStack
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    productsID INT NULL,
    materialID INT NULL,
    amount INT NULL
)
GO;

CREATE PROCEDURE updateMaterials
    (@ID INT,
     @AMOUNT INT)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE materials
    SET materialAmount = (materialAmount - @AMOUNT)
    WHERE materialID = @ID
END
```

Comment: You say you tried with a "For each Loop", do you mean a `WHILE`? What was your attempt? Please include it in your question. Sounds like you should be using a table-type parameter. Sample data and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a temp table and while loop such as :

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP_A FROM PRODUCTSTACK

DECLARE @ID INT,@AMOUNT INT

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #TEMP_A)
BEGIN
   SET @ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM PRODUCTSTACK)
   SET @AMOUNT = (SELECT TOP 1 AMOUNT FROM PRODUCTSTACK WHERE ID = @ID)
   EXEC UPDATEMATERIALS @ID,@AMOUNT
   DELETE FROM #TEMP_A WHERE ID = @ID
END
```

Comment: How would you "pass" the Temporary table to the SP? Also, why use a `WHILE` when you could far more easily use a set-based operation.

Comment: While loop can provide some advantages to logging or using a cursor which has less control in my opinion. The OP did not require to pass a temp table to the procedure, only the rows in a table to the procedure which is accomplished with the ID and AMOUNT variables.

Comment: But a Loop is a significantly slower way of doing this (and I do mean significantly). SQL isn't a programming language, it's a set-based language. Iterative tasks like this will perform awful compared to set based one.

Comment: I agree that your approach is more efficient I was trying to utilize what the OP already had in terms of his SP

Answer (score 0):

As we have no sample to base this on, this is a guess. Like I said, however, seems like a table-type parameter would do this:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.MaterialAmount AS table (ID int, Amount int);
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.UpdateMaterials @Materials dbo.MaterialAmount READONLY AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE M
    SET materialAmount = MA.Amount
    FROM dbo.materials M
         JOIN @Materials MA ON M.materialID = MA.ID;
END;
GO

--Example of usage:

DECLARE @Materials dbo.MaterialAmount;
INSERT INTO @Materials
VALUES(1,100),
      (5,20);

EXEC dbo.UpdateMaterials @Materials;
```